# Creative ways of combing different AWS products

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-sns

I have started using ec2, dynamodb, lambda, sns, cognito to port away from Parse and the more I research different AWS products it seems like many people are coming up with creative ways to structure their back end to be efficient & cheap.
Is there a creative way you've seem people work with aws products that surprised you?

Comment: not sure its a good fit for SO sites, probably better on quora or something like this

Comment: Although this is a great topic, I agree with Frédéric, I don't think this is a good fit for SO. However, I saw a talk recently about a chap using AWS lambda to parse millions of social media accounts and then trigger more lambda functions based on conditions met in previous ones.

Comment: check aws mobile blog. They have some recommended ways to use Lmabda, API gateway and Mobile hub.

Comment: Yea I know this question might not be most suitable here but still went with it since i'm on here all the time. Thank you all. But if others still wanna give  please feel free :)